# Groovy : parsing xml with HTML tags inside

Tags: html, xml, parsing, groovy

My question is about parsing XML where string values have HTML tags inside:

```
def xmlString = '''
<resource>
   <string name="my_test">No problem here!</string>
   <string name="my_text">
<b> <big>My bold and big title</big></b>
   Rest of the text
  </string>
</resource>
'''
```

(it's an Android resource file)

When I use an XmlSlurper, the HTML tags are removed. This code:

```
def resources = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString )
resources.string.each { string ->
    println "string name = " + string.@name + ", string value = " + string.text()
}
```

will produce

```
string name = my_test, string value = No problem here!
string name = my_text, string value = My bold and big title
   Rest of the text
```

I could use CDATA to prevent the HTML tags to be parsed, but then these HTML tags will not be processed when the string my_text is used.

I also tried to use a StreamingMarkupBuilder, as explained in this SO answer : [How to extract HTML Code from a XML File using groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387407/how-to-extract-html-code-from-a-xml-file-using-groovy), but then only the HTML tags and the text between them is displayed:

```
<b><big>My bold and big title</big></b>
```

and the first string is not displayed.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25140607/6509

Comment: Thx @tim_yates, this could have worked too, but I was stucked with the node and how to get the information I need from it. There is now a solution that hopefully will also help other people facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def xmlString = '''
<resource>
    <string name="my_test">No problem here!</string>
    <string name="my_text">
        <b><big>My bold and big title</big></b>
        Rest of the text
    </string>
</resource>
'''

def result = []
def resources = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xmlString).string

resources.each { resource ->
    result << new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.yield resource.getBody() }
}
```